# Making a TCP socket from scratch in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to set up a simple TCP socket in C++ without using any non-standard libraries. 
I want to make a client socket and a server client and pass an integer to the server from the client. Can someone give me a simple example of a server and a client class?

Comment: type 'socket tutorial' in google

Comment: This could be a starting point. http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: I've actually been looking on google for a while and everything I find on sockets seems to gloss over the creation and binding of port number and focuses on the send() part. Either that or the tutorial is using external non-standard libraries. Thanks for the starting point though, I will take a look.

Comment: "without any non-standard libraries". This won't work. C++ Standard Library contains only very few facilities to communicate with the OS (e.g. file streams). So you have to write OS-dependent code.... using non (C++)Standard libraries.

Comment: @DyP What I mean by non-standard is custom classes that have been tailored for specific use.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: yes, but not C++ Standard. Sorry if I mistakenly took "standard" for "C++ standard". There's no POSIX nor OS is the question.

Comment: @DyP Every C library contains the system calls for the platform. That's all you need.

Comment: @EJP I'm not that familiar with the C Standard, but a search for terms like "socket" and "connect" in the C99 doc brings no results. See also what [GNU C Std Lib says about sockets](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sockets.html#Sockets)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ does not come with a "standard library" for sockets but can of course access the standard C library for sockets.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

sockaddr_in addr;
bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(destination_address_as_32bit_number);
addr.sin_port = htons(destination_port_number_as_16bit_number);

int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
connect(s, &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

There you go...  Now you can read & write to "s" like any other file.
On the server you do it a bit different:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

sockaddr_in addr;
bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0; // bind to all interface addresses
addr.sin_port = htons(local_port_number_as_16bit_number);

int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(s, &addr, sizeof(addr));
listen(s, 50);  // 50 (the backlog) isn't really used on modern systems
int c = accept(s, &addr, sizeof(addr));  // addr gets info about client
```

An now you can read/write to "c" like any file.  "s" is the listening socket on which you do nothing but `accept()`.

Comment: Not that this answer is wrong or anything, but that is not "standard C library". It's a API provided by the OS, and the location of the header file is explicit about that.

Comment: Yes and No.  Those functions _are_ compiled C code in the standard library but are, as you imply, only a thin wrapper around the API provided by the OS.